# Moodle.sty - penalty for wrong answer in multiple-choice question

Tags: moodle

I am trying to generate a quiz in LaTeX to be imported in moodle. In a multiple choice question there are 4 choices: 3 correct answers and 1 wrong answer. Something like this:

\begin{multi}[multiple]{sum}
Indicate the correct answers:
\item* $2+2=4$
\item* $1+3=4$
\item* $0+4=4$
\item $-1+3=4$
\end{multi}

In moodle this gives 1/3 points for each correct answer and 0 points for the wrong answer. So, the student can select all answers (including the wrong one) and obtain maximum grade.

I want to avoid this and use a penalty of 50% for the wrong answer. I was trying the following:

\begin{multi}[multiple]{sum}
Indicate the correct answers:
\item* $2+2=4$
\item* $1+3=4$
\item* $0+4=4$
\item[fraction=-50] $-1+3=4$
\end{multi}

But, when imported in moodle, it shows 50% for each of the correct answers (instead of 33.3%) and -50% for the wrong one. I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong on your side: that is a bug with the moodle package.

In order to calculate the points for each correct answer marked with a star, the package computes the sum of the fractions set for all other answers, even when fractions are negative...

In your case, the sum is -50 and the package attributes `(100-(-50))/3` to each correct answer.

I think this is fixed in the development version of the moodle package that I am working on. [See here](https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle/).